# Client-Side Validation for entire model using MVC 3 (unobtrusive ajax)

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3, validation, client-side, unobtrusive-javascript

I've got client-side validation working for individual properties, however, I would like to validate at the model level (2 or more properties) using client-side validation.

I'm using `@Html.ValidationSummary(true)` to display the validation error for the Model attribute that I created.

However, when the model error is generated, it doesn't display a message.  It prevents the action from being made, but no error is displayed.

Anybody know why this would be the case?

My hunch is that it has something to do with client-side validation since server-side doesn't work in this case since I have to use an Ajax form.

Any advice would be appreciated!

**Model Attribute**

```
public class AuditDetailValidatorAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
{
    public AuditDetailValidatorAttribute()
    {
        ErrorMessage = "Must select an NCN level...";
    }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        AuditRequirementDetail audit = value as AuditRequirementDetail;

        if (audit == null || audit.AuditResult.Id == 0 || audit.AssessmentLevel.Id == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return !(audit.AuditResult.Id == 4 && audit.AssessmentLevel.Id == 1);
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        return new List<ModelClientValidationRule> 
        {
            new ModelClientValidationRule 
            {
                ValidationType = "required",
                ErrorMessage = this.ErrorMessage
            }
        };
    }
}
```

**Model Class**

```
    [AuditDetailValidator]
    public class AuditRequirementDetail
    {
        // Constructor
        public AuditRequirementDetail()
        {
            // instantiate the contained objects on AuditRequirementDetail creation
            AssessmentLevel = new AssessmentLevel();
            AuditResult = new AuditResult();
            Requirement = new RequirementDetail();
            Attachment = new Attachment();

            Counter = 0;
        }
        /* rest of the code */
     }
```

**View**

```
@model pdiqc.Models.AuditRequirement.AuditRequirementDetail

@{
    var SuccessTarget = "success" + Model.DetailID;
    var IsValidTarget = "IsValid" + Model.DetailID;
    var PerformCompletedTarget = "PerformCompleted" + Model.DetailID;
    var AuditResultTarget = "AuditResult_Id" + Model.DetailID;
    var AssessmentLevelTarget = "AssessmentLevel_Id" + Model.DetailID;
    var DesignatorTarget = "Designator_Id" + Model.DetailID;
    var EvidenceTarget = "Evidence_Id" + Model.DetailID;
    var AttachmentTarget = "Attachments_Id" + Model.DetailID;

    var AuditResultReferral = "#" + AuditResultTarget;
    var AssessmentLevelReferral = "#" + AssessmentLevelTarget;
    var DesignatorReferral = "#" + DesignatorTarget;
    var EvidenceReferral = "#" + EvidenceTarget;
    var AttachmentReferral = "#" + AttachmentTarget;
}

    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("PerformRequirement", "Audit", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", OnSuccess = "success" }, new {Class="PerformReqForm" }))
    {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        if ((Model.AuditResult.Id == 1 && Model.AssessmentLevel.Id > 1) || Model.Evidence == string.Empty || Model.Evidence == null)
        {
            <input class="@IsValidTarget" name="IsValid" type="hidden" value=false />
        }
        else
        {
            <input class="@IsValidTarget" name="IsValid" type="hidden" value=true />
        }

       <p class="reqText">@Model.RequirementLabel.ConfigurableLabelDesc #@ViewBag.PerformCounter - @ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(x => x.Requirement.Text, ViewData).SimpleDisplayText</p>
       <div class="hide">
       /* REST OF CODE */
    }
```

Comment: which are the properties on which you want to apply validation ?

Comment: Here are the properties I'm validating against:         
            return !(audit.AuditResult.Id == 4 && audit.AssessmentLevel.Id == 1);

Comment: Basically, if "auditresult.id" is 4 AND audit.assessmentlevel.id is 1, the model is not valid.

Comment: have you tried adding a breakpoint in the `IsValid()` method and check if its working as you want it to ?

Comment: Well, I know it's working.  It successfully writes to the database when it's successful.  The validation I have up above prevents it from writing to the database.  The problem is the error message doesn't display.  So when you click on the submit button, nothing happens.  I'd like to have an error message show up.

Comment: You have to wire it up with the client / jquery unobtrusive

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a custom validator for a checkbox to make sure it was cheeked and had to do the following.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.addBool('requiredcheckbox', 'required');
    }(jQuery));
</script>
```

Also include @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x=>x.yourProp)